# Android background string resource

Tags: android, xml, layout, colors, background

I am working on a layout XML file, and I want to set a background color for a LinearLayout. This bit, which I am now using, works perfectly:

```
android:background="#1a64b7"
```

However, I would much prefer to break that out. In my strings.xml file I have

```
<string name="bg_blue">#1a64b7</string>
```

but when I use that in the following manner:

```
android:background="@string/bg_blue"
```

it shows up great in the Graphical Layout Preview in Eclipse, but the app crashes as soon as it opens. Any ideas? Thanks a ton.

Nick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/values/colors.html) is the right way to do it!

For example you need some resources xml with lines like:

```
<resources>
    <color name="candidate_normal">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="candidate_recommended">#FFE35900</color>
    <color name="candidate_other">#ff808080</color>
    <color name="candidate_background">#bbffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Ah, this is why I love StackOverflow. You guys are like magic. Thank you!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practise to keep your colors defined in colors.xml, and reference them as "@color/bg_blue". Keep your strings.xml for language copy only.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: should colors.xml by placed into the values folder?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape that pound symbol.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling